# Why I cannot find google Cantonese input in play store?

Tags: google-play-store

I watched this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jqz3Fv9PcRo

I want to download the same app, the video was just a few months old. However, I could not find the app.

My location is US.

Comment: The developer has may be restricted the app for your region, or your devices doesn't meet the requirement that the app requires, etc. Try contacting the devs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the package name of the app you are talking about is `com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.cantonese` I didn't find any thing on play store There might be 3 reasons for it

Reason 1 `->` The app is not available in your region

Reason 2 `->` Your device does not support the App

Reason 3 `->` The App was unlisted from playstore

the first option seems more likely

Any way you can always download the APK from external sources , might not be the safest but it works